# Object reference is not set to an instance Access query C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query into the Clients table, when the user enters a mobile number, the code checks if it matches any record, if it does, it returns the client's Name & Address into text boxes, but I'm getting this error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" by the time I enter anything into that textbox

here is the code, what could be the problem?

```
  private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clientsearch();
        clientsearch2();
    }

    public void clientsearch()
    {
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
        {

            conn.Open();
            string query = @"select Cname From Clients where Cmobile = @mobile";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = textBox11.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            textBox12.Text = @result;
        }
    }
    public void clientsearch2()
    {
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
        {

            conn.Open();
            string query = @"select Caddress From Clients where Cmobile = @mobile";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = textBox11.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            textBox13.Text = @result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using a debugger or show the full exception detail. But I would guess that your line: `cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` could be the cause.

Comment: Also upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 if you can. Visual Studio 2017 no longer gives you this unhelpful error when you debug, but will instead tell the exact part of the code that caused it. VS 2017 is currently in RC and will be fully released early next month (March 7th I believe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
textBox12.Text = @result;
```

`@result` isn't anything. You just want `result`. Additionally, sending separate queries to the server for this data is pointlessly inefficient. Do this instead:

```
public void clientsearch()
{
    string query = @"select Cname, Caddress  From Clients where Cmobile LIKE  @mobile + '*'";
    using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
    using (var cmd = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = textBox11.Text;
        conn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                textBox12.Text = rdr["Cname"].ToString();
                textBox13.Text = rdr["Caddress"].ToString();
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, it's better style to also abstract your database code away from user interface. Ideally you would return a `Client` class, but since I don't see one I'll show an example using a tuple instead:

```
public Tuple<string, string> FindClientByMobile(string mobile)
{
    string query = @"SELECT Cname, Caddress FROM Clients WHERE Cmobile LIKE @mobile + '*'";
    using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
    using (var cmd = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = mobile;
        conn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            rdr.Read();
            return Tuple<string, string>.Create(rdr["Cname"].ToString(), rdr["Caddress"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you're playing with a Visual Studio 2017 release candidate, you can also use the new Tuple shortcuts:

```
public (string, string) FindClientByMobile(string mobile)
{
    string query = @"SELECT Cname, Caddress FROM Clients WHERE Cmobile LIKE @mobile + '*'";
    using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
    using (var cmd = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = mobile;
        conn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            rdr.Read();
            return (rdr["Cname"].ToString(), rdr["Caddress"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And then use them like this:

```
private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = FindClientByMobile(textBox11.Text);
    textBox12.Text = result.Item1;
    textBox13.Text = result.Item2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Joel, but I've used your code, and it returns no data, but no more error.

Comment: Make sure your search **exactly** matches the number as it is stored. I bet you want a `LIKE` expression in the SQL, rather than an `=` expression.

Comment: I'm sure it matches it, but will try with the like expression

Comment: An example is in my answer. Note that TextChanged fires with _every keystroke_. It fires as you type text, not when you're finished.

Comment: just a question, if the number starts with a 0, would that cause it to not return any results? in my country all mobile numbers starts with 0

Comment: Are you storing the value as a text value or a numeric value? Numbers do not have _any_ formatting. Access and VB.net see the number `0123456` as `123456`.

Comment: well, i've set the column properties to text not number, I'm adding it manually in access file for testing

Comment: The VB code is using `OleDbType.Integer`, which tells ADO.Net to convert it to integer, which will not care about things like leading zeroes. The whole reason you set an explicit type here rather than just using `AddWithValue` is so you can set that type to exactly match the database column.

Comment: I've tested it again, I stored the Cmobile as 12345, and when search it returned the result. is there a way to make it search with the 0 at the start?

Comment: Read my previous comment and think about what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joel, I've changed to OleDbType.VarChar instead of Integer and it worked perfectly, thanks for being patient to answer my question, was completely lost :D